# What is the verb used for check payments?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What is the verb used when a bank check has been paid?
Is the word `cleared`?
**EDIT:**
To be more specific, I'm looking for the word that means the check has been completely processed and it has either been cashed or deposited to another account. Should I just use the words `cashed` or `deposited`?

Comment: If the bank has decided that a check you **deposited** had enough money on the account it was paid against, they would clear it and the check would have been cleared

Comment: Instead of depositing it, you can also **cash** it. Of course, the bank will again first clear it.

Comment: So after the check has been cleared the money has been transferred where it should have, right?

Comment: Not *cleared*. I would think *paid* is the only word that actually means 'paid' in this context. What's wrong with *paid*?

Comment: @Kris When when I say I have paid you by check, it means I've written you a check. It doesn't mean you have cashed it, right?

Comment: Not you, but it is the check that has been 'paid'. It makes a lot of difference.

Comment: *The check I gave you is now Paid (by the bank to you).* The money has reached the hands of the payee, after having moved out of the payer's account and cleared along the way.

Comment: @Kris Just double checking: when I say a check has been paid, it means the money has been transacted from source account to another account, or it has been cashed, right? I mean it's no longer in the source account, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the word you are looking for is ***cleared***

1. someone **pays** you with a cheque.
2. you **deposit** you have money now on your account
3. within a few days/a week the bank **clears** the cheque at the other bank and you can keep the money - the cheque has **cleared**
4. if it does NOT **clear**, it **bounces** and the amount is deducted from your account

2a. if you **cash** it, the bank has to clear it immediately or will deduct the amount from your account if it does not clear, so you will need to have an account in that bank

UK Barclay cycle

http://ask.barclays.co.uk/help/day2day_banking/chequeclearing

Comment: If I cash the check in step 2 and do not deposit it to my account how can the bank deduct the amount from my account if it bounces? It seems a little odd. I'd appreciate an explanation but I don't wanna make this a financial question. I'm just looking for the right word to mean I have the money for sure (no going back) and I guess you're proposing `clear`.

Comment: @AtoMerZ In most circumstances, you cannot cash a cheque and must deposit it. If it's cashed immediately and is subsequently dishonoured, the bank reclaims the money it gave you (either in cash or into your account) by deducting it from your account.

Answer (score 3):

The word used in the UK is ***cleared***.

> **23.** To pass (a bill, cheque, through-ticket) through the Clearing-House.
>
> > 1868   J. E. T. Rogers *Man. Polit. Econ.* (1876) xi. 148   Many millions in value of such bills [of exchange] are weekly cleared through the London bankers.
>
> [OED]